# Flags in cabal files

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am following the user-guide for package developing: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#quickstart

I got stuck in the `Flags` section. How do I pass flags to my files? Is it just at `build` time? I have tried to search for it, but found no useful information - just the command option `--flags`.

`cabal build -f debug` doesn't work

```
Flag Debug
    Description: Enable debug support
    Manual: True
    Default: False

BenchMark bench-foo
    ghc-options:        -Wall
    type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
    default-language:   Haskell2010
    build-depends:      base, time
    main-is:            bench-foo.hs
    if flag(debug) && os(windows)
        main-is:        bench-bar.hs
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pass the flags to `cabal configure`, e.g.:

```
cabal configure -f debug
```

Answer (score 6):

With Stack, use

```
stack build --flag <pkg>:debug
```

to set `debug` flag to `True` for `<pkg>`, or use `--flag '*:debug'` to set `debug` flag to `True` for all packages. Replace `debug` with `-debug` to set `debug` flag to `False`.

You can also specify flag settings in a `stack.yaml` file. For example, to set `debug` flag to `False` for `<pkg>`, add this to your `stack.yaml`:

```
flags:
  <pkg>:
    debug: false
```

Answer (score 5):

With `cabal-2.1.0` you can do it like this:

```
cabal new-build -f debug
```